# Can anybody help me in including leap controls in TrackballControls.js

Tags: three.js, leap-motion

I am learning leap motion controls and I need help in including leap controls in Trackballcontrols.js link is provided below http://threejsdoc.appspot.com/doc/three.js/src.source/extras/controls/TrackballControls.js.html

Comment: I am new to three.js and leap motion and trying to integrate leapmotion controls for the Below example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

Comment: What actual gesture(s) do you wish to support? I presume you wish to track your hand(s) or finger(s) to control the camera position in 3 dimensions? It'd be good to confirm that though.

Answer (score 3):

Check out

https://github.com/spren9er/threeleapcontrols

and look at the example file. There is one javascript file named LeapCameraControls.js for controlling the camera and another one named LeapObjectControls.js for controlling objects.

Both controls are fully customizable, i.e. you can specify which gesture (how many hands and fingers, palm or finger tip position, left or right-handed) should be used for rotating, zooming/scaling or panning the camera or object respectively.

In action:

http://youtu.be/SQDAa-cqlrA

Answer (score 0):

Are you using leap.js? If not - it should help:

https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs

Check out Robbie Tilton's earth rotation example:

https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs/tree/master/examples/earthRotation

Here's a video demo:

https://vimeo.com/57873675

(I presume you wish to have a similar interaction, but with the periodic table?)